# Remove character from string ignoring first match using regex

Tags: regex, r

How can all instances of a character be removed from a string **except for the first match** using regex? In the example data below I'd like to keep the first '-' and remove all other instances.

```
myvec <- c("12-34-5678-9", "ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL-MN", "9-8765", "a - defgh -- ijkl")
```

The outcome sought is:

```
"12-3456789"   "ABC-DEFGHIJKLMN"   "9-8765"   "a - defgh  ijkl"
```

I worked out a solution using `strsplit` and rebuilt the vectors using `paste` but I'm looking for a regex approach to satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use capturing group.

```
> myvec <- c("12-34-5678-9", "ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL-MN", "9-8765", "a - defgh -- ijkl")
> gsub("^([^-]*-)|-", "\\1", myvec)
[1] "12-3456789"      "ABC-DEFGHIJKLMN" "9-8765"         
[4] "a - defgh  ijkl"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 gsub('^[^-]+-(*SKIP)(*F)|-', '', myvec, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "12-3456789"      "ABC-DEFGHIJKLMN" "9-8765"          "a - defgh  ijkl"
```